# Set xlPrimary and xlSecondary axis as percentage not working

Tags: excel, vba, charts

Im not able to set `xlPrimary` AND `xlSecondary` axis as percentage. Only 1/2 is set as percentage and I can't understand why.

I tried this line of code to set my axis as percentage :

```
Set cht = Output.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    With cht
        .ChartArea.ClearContents
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
         xdata = EnregistrementsSecteurs
         ydata = EnregistrementsValeurs
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xdata
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = ydata
            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Rating"
        .Axes(xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
    End With

Set cht = Output.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    With cht
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = xlSecondary
        .FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
        .SeriesCollection(2).Values = TValues
        .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Y"
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(3).AxisGroup = xlSecondary
        .FullSeriesCollection(3).ChartType = xlLine
        .SeriesCollection(3).Values = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet").Range("D3:D12").Value
        .SeriesCollection(3).Name = "T"
        .Axes(xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
    End With
```

It is working only If I have one scale. When I got 2 scale on same chart, only one axes is set to %.

The Output of the above code :

[image]

Comment: @BigBen this seems not working when I have 2 Axis Group In Same Chart

Comment: @BigBen I just edited I don't understand why `xlSecondary` isn't set as %

Comment: Try `.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary)`

Comment: The trick is the macro recorder :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Specify the axes `Type`:

```
.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
```

Comment: Any Idea why : `.Axes(xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%"` works when I have only one axis ? (I don't need to specify `xlValue` there).

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. My first guess would be that it's applied to the `xlValue` axis by default, but that doesn't explain why you need to specify `xlValue` for the secondary axis.

Answer (score 0):

As Bigben mentioned, we need to apply data label before applying.
I have checked the below code it is working for me. I have used the sample range.

```
 Sub test1()
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets("sheet1").Shapes
    
    Debug.Print ws.Name
    
    Dim EnregistrementsSecteurs As Range
    
    Dim EnregistrementsValeurs As Range
    
    Set EnregistrementsValeurs = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B2:B6")
    Set EnregistrementsSecteurs = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2:A6")
    
    Next
    
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
        With cht
            .ChartArea.ClearContents
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
             xdata = EnregistrementsSecteurs
             ydata = EnregistrementsValeurs
                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xdata
                .SeriesCollection(1).Values = ydata
                .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Rating"
                .SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
                .SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: It is not what I am looking for, I want to set `TickLabels` format. This does not work with chart having both `xlPrimary` and `xlSecondary` axis. All the time, only 1 of those is not set as percentage.

Comment: I full edited my issue, maybe it is not missleading now. Please have a look